# fortran 2003 seg fault with overridden type-bound procedure

Tags: oop, overriding, fortran

I'm trying to use some of the object-oriented features of Fortran 2003 and I'm running into some trouble. First off, I have an abstract data type sparse_matrix:

```
type, abstract :: sparse_matrix
    (some data)
contains
    procedure(matrix_vector_multiply), deferred :: matvec
end type sparse_matrix

abstract interface
    subroutine matrix_vector_multiply(A,x,y)
        import :: sparse_matrix
        class (sparse_matrix), intent(in) :: A
        real(kind=8), dimension(:) :: x,y
    end subroutine matrix_vector_multiply
end abstract interface
```

then I have a concrete data type which inherits from sparse_matrix

```
type, extends(sparse_matrix) :: csr_sparse_matrix
    (some more data)
contains
    procedure :: matvec => csr_matvec
end type csr_sparse_matrix
```

and the actual implementation of matvec:

```
subroutine csr_matvec(A,x,y)
    class (csr_sparse_matrix), intent(in) :: A
    real(kind=8), dimension(:) :: x,y
    (do stuff)
end subroutine csr_matvec
```

Later, I want to use matvec in a different module, and I don't care which dynamic type I've got:

```
subroutine solve(A,x,b,tolerance)
    class (sparse_matrix), intent(in) :: A
    real(kind=8), dimension(:), intent(in) :: b
    real(kind=8), dimension(:), intent(out) :: x
    real(kind=8), intent(in) :: tolerance
    real(kind=8), dimension( A%nrow ) :: z

    call A%matvec(b,z)
    (more stuff)
end subroutine solver
```

My understanding is that everything should work fine, no matter what dynamic type A is, so long as the subroutine `matvec` has been overridden in the child data type.

This code compiles just fine, but it seg faults when I run it. When I change the declaration of the matrix in the `solve` procedure as follows:

```
     class (csr_sparse_matrix), intent(in) :: A
```

it works just fine. Likewise, if I leave A as a sparse_matrix but use

```
select type(A)
type is (csr_sparse_matrix)
    (the same stuff)
end select
```

then everything runs fine too. But this defeats the whole purpose of overriding the procedures of an abstract type in the first place -- the program shouldn't care what kind of matrix I'm using, as long as it can perform a matrix-vector multiplication.

Anyhow, I'm sure it's just a matter of some attribute that I forgot to include, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Be aware there are compiler bugs in polymorphic features all around. I submitted several reports for gfortran ans ifort just last month. What compiler version do you use.

Comment: Also, do not use `real(kind=8)`, you probably wanted `selected_real_kind(p=15,r=200)`, or `real64`.

Comment: I'm using gfortran -- I thought it worked pretty much fine as of version 4.6 with F2003.

Still fairly certain that this is my fault and not the compiler's.

Comment: Are all procedures called with an explicit interface accessible?

Comment: By accessible, do you mean public vs. private? They're all public.

Comment: I was just making sure that `solver` wasn't an external subprogram.  I missed the words "in a different module" in the description.  As Vladimir says, there is the distinct possibility of compiler issues in this area.  Time to start detailed debugging/chopping back to a minimal example that demonstrates the crash.

Comment: Verdammt! I tried making ``solver`` a non-overridable type-bound procedure of the abstract sparse matrix data type and putting it in the same module, but then... oh boy did stuff start to break.

Comment: Your gfortran version is not the latest stable release (4.7.2), which may be one source of error. I tried a (non-functional) copy of your code and it compiles and executes fine with both gfortran 4.7.2 and ifort 13. That said, gfortran does still produce a segfault upon trying `procedure, non_overridable :: matvec => csr_matvec` and this is a compiler error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it was the compiler after all; I was using gfortran 4.6.3, whereas abstract data types were only properly supported as of gfortran 4.7. Unfortunately, this makes my code not so portable, as the long-term support releases of several linux distributions only include version 4.6.